# Can't find so many predefined file types in Eclipse Kepler

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler

I have downloaded a new Eclipse Kepler IDE yesterday and I am unable to find the dynamic web project template and all other related files in there like jsp file, servlet etc. This means I am unable to create these files directly by choosing from wizard, like I was doing in Eclipse Helios. Also, it's not possible to run the previous projects that were built using Eclipse Helios? Does Kepler support web projects or not, or am I the only one who is struggling with this problem? I am using java since two weeks now, so I don't have much experience with other Eclipse versions too. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you got the wrong distribution. You probably want the "Eclipse for Java EE developers" distribution, since that includes web development tools etc. by default.

Comment: can u provide me the link please? where to get this?